# Elasticsearch multi lanuage per-index approache - how to remove duplicates?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the same resources in multi language. I decided on the approach "language per-index" - index-en, index-fr, index-de... (My documents are large and have many text fields).

Each document has own unique field (e.g. id) in all index. Example:

- index-en - id: 0
- index-fr - id: 0
- index-de - id: 0

I have also flag `main` which determine which language is main. Only one language (index) can be main for document with the same id. Example:

- index-en - id: 0; main: true
- index-fr - id: 0; main: false
- index-de - id: 0; main: false

When I run query I would like get only one document with the same id - from one index. The perfect solution should look like this:

1. Try find one document (from one index) with prefer language
2. If not found then find one document (from one index) where `main=true`

Maybe better will be switch to approach "language per-field". I think that with the approach will be hard manage mapping (I have to plan more languages).

I hope that is understandable. I would be very grateful for your help.